# joomla K2 limit items per page

Tags: pagination, joomla1.7, joomla-k2

I have installed K2 component in Joomla 1.7.

In one of my pages (not the front page) I am listing articles from 2 categories (News, newsflash).

The problem is I cannot find any pagination support. I do not want to display all 
articles in the same page. I'd rather display e.g. 10 items/articles per page.

How can I do that? Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are displaying items from more than one category, you set the display parameters in the menu item properties.